# FilenameFilter through subdirectories in Java

Tags: java, android, mp3

I am creating an android app that will search through a directory, grab all files that end with .mp3 and add them to an array list. I have the starting point at /sdcard/, but not all of the music files are directly in that path. The rest are in /sdcard/Music/(artist)/.... I am trying to get my FilenameFilter to continue through the subdirectories and then add it to the list. Here's the code that I'm working with:

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
        return(name.endsWith(".mp3")&& dir.isDirectory());
    }

    private void updatePlaylist() {
        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length>0){
            for(File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do a recursive call like this:

```
private void updatePlaylist() {
  File home = new File(SD_PATH);
  addToSongs(home);
  if(songs.length>0){

    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item, songs);
    setListAdapter(songList);
  }

}

private void addToSongs(home)
  for(File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){

   if(file.isDirectory()){
     //recursive call
     addToSongs(file);
   } else{
     songs.add(file.getName());`
   }
}
```

Comment: There weren't any errors, but it didn't add anymore songs or folders. Is there a way to just show the folder? Not necessarily empty the .mp3 files from the folder, but just show the folder and be able to navigate through it manually?